# Does Snowflake preserve retrieval order?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Posting two questions:
1.
Let's say there is a query:
`SELECT C1, C2, C3 from TABLE`;

When this query is fired for the first time,it retrieves all the values in a certain order.

Next time, when the same query is fired, will the previous order be retained?

2. There are 2 tables, TABLE1 and TABLE2, both of them have identical data.

Will (`SELECT * from TABLE1`) and (`SELECT * from TABLE1`) retrieve the same order of rows?

Comment: Never assume that you get the same order, without an ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Period.  There is no ordering in a result set unless you explicitly include an `ORDER BY`.

It is that simple.  If you want data in a particular order, then you need to use `ORDER BY`.  That is how relational databases work.

The same query can return results in different orders each time the query is executed.  There are no guarantees about the order -- unless the query has an `ORDER BY` for the outermost `SELECT`.

Comment: To add to Gordon's response.  The question about Table1 and Table2 having identical data...same answer.  No guarantees.  In fact, the storage of the data on Table1 and Table2 can be completely different, so the order is almost certain to be returned differently.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, unless you are fetching data from result cache!
2. No, unless they are very small tables and your query runs with low parallelism.

Sorry for extra answer, but I see Tim claims that the query will return same result as long as the underlying table(s) is not modified, and the query has same execution plan.

Snowflake executes the queries in parallel, therefore the order of data is not predictable unless ORDER BY is used.

Let's create a table (big enough to be processed in parallel), and run a simple test case:

```
-- running on medium warehouse

create or replace table my_test_table ( id number, name varchar ) as
select seq4(), 'gokhan' || seq4() from table(generator(rowcount=>1000000000));

alter session set USE_CACHED_RESULT = false;

select * from my_test_table  limit 10;
```

You will see that it will return different rows every time you run.

Comment: Tim has been proven incorrect, and he doesn't mind that, because he learned something new today about how Snowflake works +1.

Comment: Also, I've seen cached resultsets return in different order.  If the resultset is large, it is stored in multiple files at the services layer and can be fetched in a different order.  It's not common, but it can happen.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that about large cached resultsets. Thanks @MikeWalton

Answer (score 0):

To answer both questions short: No.

If your query has no ORDER BY-clause, the SELECT statement always returns an unordered set. This means: Even if you query the same table twice and the data didnt change, SELECT without ORDER BY can retrieve different row-orders.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/select.html

Comment: Not sure I agree with the `and the data didnt change` part of your answer.  The Snowflake documentation doesn't explicitly say this; it only says the same select can generate a different order, without actually giving the conditions when that might occur.

Comment: I think the answer here is just trying to state that the assumption is that the data hasn't changed, since if the data has changed, the result would be different regardless of the order, anyway.  I don't think Marcel is trying to say that this is the only time the results may be different.  That's my interpretation, anyway.

Comment: True @Mike. Sorry for being Not so accurate.